# How can we define the infinite sum of $1$ and $-1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

$1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1......$

it seems first that this is equal to $0$

but we re-arrange this sum

$1+(1-1)+(1-1)..... $

so the sum is $1$

In this case,

do we say that this sum is undefined?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, we say the series is divergent, and its sum is undefined. But to answer the question in the title:

> How can we define the infinite sum of 1 and -1?

There are various definitions of generalized sums that apply to divergent series. The most important methods that apply to this series are listed here: [Wikipedia:Summation of Grandi's series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_of_Grandi%27s_series). Briefly, the Cesàro sum, Abel sum, and Borel sum of the series is $\frac12$.

Comment: We can also write 1-1+1-1+...=(1-1)+(1-1)+...=0+0+...=0. The usual sum doesn't exist.

Comment: @user254665 It's true that the usual sum doesn't exist. But be careful with the reasoning. Because the series is divergent, the first equality, "1-1+1-1+...=(1-1)+(1-1)+...", is wrong. Either we interpret the ellipsis as ordinary summation, in which case the left side of the equation is undefined, or we interpret it as something like Abel summation, in which case it asserts 1/2 = 0.

Comment: I just wanted to show the OP that if his method was valid then so is mine, and 1=0. There is a family of cardinal $c$ of  members of $l_{\infty}^*$, ,each of norm $1$,  that  are generalized limits.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly  for each $n \in \mathbb N$,
$$U_n=(-1)^n$$

Now observe that

$U_{2n}=(-1)^{2n}=1$ and

$U_{2n+1}=(-1)^{2n+1}=-1$ .

So $$U_n= \begin{cases}
 ~~~1&  ; n \text{ is  even}\\ 
 -1& ; n \text{ is  odd}
\end{cases}$$

Then $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}U_n \neq 0$  $\Rightarrow \sum U_n$ diverges.

Comment: BTW you can use `\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}` as explained [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5025#5025).